# LinqToExcel file delete IOException after read

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-excel

I have a class that reads excel worksheet names using LinqToExcel.

```
 public class ExcelREader: IReader
 {
    public IEnumerable<string> GetWorksheetNames(_fileName)
    {
        using (var excelQueryFactory = new ExcelQueryFactory(_fileName))
        {
            return excelQueryFactory.GetWorksheetNames();
        }
    }
 }
```

And I am using in my asp.net mvc project.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
   
    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), file.FileName);
    file.SaveAs(path);
    
    var reader = new ExcelREader();
    var items = reader.GetWorksheetNames(path);
 
    File.Delete(path);
 
    return View();
}
```

But File.Delete(path) throws an exception. "The process cannot access the file 'XXX' because it is being used by another process."

I used `using` keyword. And used `GC.Collect();` or `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();` methods but not worked.

Comment: I bet is `HttpPostedFileBase file` who lock your file. You should find a way to dispose that class before deleting the file.

Comment: No, I commented the excel read rows, file deleted successfull. I think the excel reader locks the file.

Answer (score 1):

Set the **UsePersistentConnection** property to *false*:

```
var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory(fileName)
{
    UsePersistentConnection = false
};
```